# Quel est le bon accord des pronoms (relatifs et personnels) dans la phrase suivante ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, accord, pronoms-relatifs, pronoms-personnels

Voici ma phrase initiale :

> Étant las de l’intense accumulation de nuages grisâtres avec **laquelle**
>   il était entouré, l’astre radieux décida de **la** dégager.

Je ne suis pas sûr si les mots en gras sont employé correctement. La phrase doit-elle être écrite ainsi ?

> Étant las de l’intense accumulation de nuages grisâtres avec **lesquels**
>   il était entouré, l’astre radieux décida de **les** dégager.

Ce que je veux dire est si les pronoms doivent être accordés au singulier ou au pluriel, i.e. avec `l’intense accumulation` ou `nuages grisâtres` ?

Comment: Les deux phrases sont correctes, mais la seconde est plus naturelle, car l'oreille accorde avec le plus proche

Answer (score 3):

On est entouré par, plutôt qu'entouré avec et le soleil ne va pas dégager (libérer) les nuages mais s'en extraire, je corrigerai donc la deuxième phrase en:

> Étant las de l’intense accumulation de nuages grisâtres par lesquels il était entouré, l’astre radieux décida de s'en dégager.

Pour ce qui est du choix de l'accord, comme @cl-r l'a déjà indiqué dans son commentaire, les deux sujets sont possibles: l'astre est entouré par des nuages ou l'astre est entouré pas une accumulation de nuages. La première forme est plus courante.

Comment: Courante, comme « il vaut mieux l'utiliser » ?

Comment: Oui car elle ne risque pas de surprendre le lecteur ou auditeur.

Comment: Si tu utilises une subordonée pour déterminer de quels nuages il s'agit, il faut utiliser un article défini (ils semblent tous faire partie de l'accumulation) : « l'intense accumulation *des* nuages [qui l'entouraient] ». Autrement, utiliser *de* suggère plutôt l'accord avec *accumulation*. « L'intense accumulation de nuages qui l'entourait ».